# how do I use an raspberry pi 3 A+ with 3.5 inch touch gpio display(MPI3501)(ILI9486 based)

Tags: display, lcd, pitft, pi-3a+

I have a 3.5-inch display(MPI3501)(ILI9486 based) and a Raspberry Pi 3A+.

The Datasheet-

https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2278271.pdf

Here are the specifications.

The library link-

github.com/goodtft/LCD-show

The LCD world link-

lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display

It interfaces over SPI and plugs into the first 26 pins.

The display runs off power from the GPIO.

I'm running Raspbian.

The display has a 26 pin connector for easy attachment.

I get no error messages whatsoever.

[image]

[image]

I tried LCD-world's libraries.

The scripts run and the pi reboots, but the output looked white and blank like this-

[image]

https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show

I ran the following commands

```
sudo rm -rf LCD-show
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

this is what LCD35 looks like-

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ./system_backup.sh

if [ -f /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf ]; then
sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
fi
if [ ! -d /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d ]; then
sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
fi
sudo cp ./usr/tft35a-overlay.dtb /boot/overlays/
sudo cp ./usr/tft35a-overlay.dtb /boot/overlays/tft35a.dtbo
root_dev=`grep -oPr "root=[^\s]*" /boot/cmdline.txt | awk -F= '{printf $NF}'`
if test "$root_dev" = "/dev/mmcblk0p7";then
sudo cp -rf ./boot/config-noobs-nomal.txt ./boot/config.txt.bak
else
sudo cp -rf ./boot/config-nomal.txt ./boot/config.txt.bak
sudo echo "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" >> ./boot/config.txt.bak
fi
sudo echo "dtparam=i2c_arm=on" >> ./boot/config.txt.bak
sudo echo "dtparam=spi=on" >> ./boot/config.txt.bak
sudo echo "enable_uart=1" >> ./boot/config.txt.bak
sudo echo "dtoverlay=tft35a:rotate=90" >> ./boot/config.txt.bak
sudo cp -rf ./boot/config.txt.bak /boot/config.txt

sudo cp -rf ./usr/99-calibration.conf-35-90  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf
sudo cp -rf ./usr/99-fbturbo.conf  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf
if test "$root_dev" = "/dev/mmcblk0p7";then
sudo cp ./usr/cmdline.txt-noobs /boot/cmdline.txt
else
sudo cp ./usr/cmdline.txt /boot/
fi
sudo cp ./usr/inittab /etc/
#sudo cp ./boot/config-35.txt /boot/config.txt
sudo touch ./.have_installed
echo "gpio:resistance:35:90:480:320" > ./.have_installed
#evdev install
#nodeplatform=`uname -n`
#kernel=`uname -r`
version=`uname -v`
#if test "$nodeplatform" = "raspberrypi";then
#echo "this is raspberrypi kernel"
version=${version##* }
#version=${version#*#}
echo $version
if test $version -lt 2017;then
echo "reboot"
else
echo "need to update touch configuration"
sudo dpkg -i -B ./xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.6-1+b1_armhf.deb 2> error_output.txt
#sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev  2> error_output.txt
result=`cat ./error_output.txt`
echo -e "\033[31m$result\033[0m"
grep -q "error:" ./error_output.txt && exit
sudo cp -rf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/45-evdev.conf
#echo "reboot"
fi
#else
#echo "this is not raspberrypi kernel, no need to update touch configure, reboot"
#fi

sudo sync
sudo sync
sleep 1
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
sudo ./rotate.sh $1
elif [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
echo "Too many parameters"
fi

echo "reboot now"
sudo reboot
```

I tried changing the power source but it was the same. I checked the compatibility for the display. It supports a 3A+. The Pi restarts.
I am interfacing over Vnc and ssh cuz the HDMI is disabled during the use of the SPI display.

I ran a command to check the version

```
uname -v
```

returning

```
#1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:45:19 BST 2020
```

and

```
uname -r
```

returning

```
5.4.51-v7+
```

and

```
lsb_release -a
```

returning

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

P.S

Also, tell me if you know any other 3.5-inch display libraries with touch support. Thanks!

Comment: This is the **third** time you have asked the same (or similar) questions. You have FAILED to provide the most basic information i.e. the SPECIFICATIONS of the screen.

Comment: And stop posting a bunch of pictures, post specification and references (URL) instead!

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I am deeply sorry. I realise I should read more questions before posting mine. here are the specifications.
the library link
https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show
the link LCD world link
http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display

Comment: i'll add more to the question in a bit give me 20 min

Comment: @IsaiahPaul You should also take the advice you got and not disrespect them!

Comment: @MatsKarlsson 
I made some changes

Comment: @Milliways I made some changes based on what I could find. Is this enough?

Answer (score 1):

**Please read:**

1. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
2. The comments from the previous post, they have incredibly good advice! They are quoted below for your convenience.

First thing is to describe the actual hardware you have - what screen, how it's connected, where it was from and version of the OS you are using. So far there are more versions of screen than I have Pi boards handy... without this basic info no one will know where to start to help you. Also general statements like tried multiple times with changing stuff I knew but I failed does not say what you did and if you saw any messages... It's worth sitting down and thinking about your problem from our point - we cannot see what you can or know what you have done. – **Andyroo Oct 8**

@IsaiahPaul sit down in front of your Raspberry Pi ... look at it very carefully and describe to a blind person what you see ... put that description into your post – **jsotola Oct 9**

Comment: @jsotola is this enough.